# Difference between "get out " and "climb out" of the bed

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

Is there any difference between "to get out of the bed" and "to climb out of the bed"?
Any change in the meaning?

Comment: Only if the bed is unusually high!

Comment: those should both be "to get out of bed" and "to climb out of bed" respectively if you want to sound natural

Comment: "Climb out" sounds like it's a little more effort.

Comment: **Climb out of bed** better suits those double and triple type bunk beds that are often seen in children's bedrooms, with a ladder attached.

Comment: Feather beds engulf you. *Climbing out* makes it sound too easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get out of bed" Is a normal way of saying it. Nothing unusual. "climb out" of bed indicates it was hard to do.

examples:

> When I finally climbed out of bed, it was already 2pm

> I got out of bed at 9am yesterday